# No output data at all for Producer/Consumer threading

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, bufferedreader, producer-consumer

**Edit:**
I have a producer class that send some data to the SharedBuffer class. This data is added to an ArrayList with the limit set to 100. There is no problem with adding data to said list, but the consumer class does not manage to get any of the data out of the list.

No output is produced at all (no null or errors).

**Edit 2:** The method for putting data inside the array was added.

SharedBuffer class:

```
    static final int RESOURCE_LIMIT = 100;

    private List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
//  private boolean done = false;


    public boolean isFull(){
        return data.size() >= RESOURCE_LIMIT;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return data.size() <= 0;
    }

    public synchronized void putData(String s){
        while(this.isFull()){
            try{
                wait();
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                //
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        data.add(s);
        //size works and there is data in list.
        //System.out.println(data.size() + data.get(0)); 

        public boolean isEmpty(){
            return data.size() <= 0;
        }

        public synchronized String getData(){
            while(this.isEmpty()){
                try{
                    wait();
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            String s_data = (String)(data.get(0));
            if(s_data != null){
                data.remove(s_data);
                System.out.println(s_data);
            }
            return s_data;
        }
```

Consumer class:

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            String line = buffer.getData();
            if(line != null){
                System.out.println(line);

                //do stuff with the data.
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about your problem and post only relevant code.

Comment: I have edited the post. I hope it is better now.

Comment: How do you put data in buffer.

Comment: Your `isEmpty` method must be synchronized too because it access `data` field.

Comment: I have added the put method, but I doubt that is the problem.

Comment: Your code isn't compiles, but your problem that you do not invoke `notifyAll` in your put method. You also should invoke it in get method too.

Comment: I tried to add synchronized to both the isEmpty and isFull, that did not change anything.

Comment: Synchronizing them do not fix current problem, but prevent some problem in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code (add `notyfyAll()` invokation)

```
public synchronized void putData(String s){
    while(this.isFull()){
        try{
            wait();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            //
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    data.add(s);
    notifyAll();
}

public synchronized String getData(){
    while(this.isEmpty()){
        try{
            wait();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    String s_data = (String)(data.get(0));
    if(s_data != null){
        data.remove(s_data);
        System.out.println(s_data);
    }
    notifyAll();
    return s_data;
}
```

Also you should synchronize `isEmpty` and `isFull` methods because the access to `data`.

Comment: Ah, I see. I never wake up the consumer.